# Any ideas why results of query are not being displayed as Checkboxes?

Tags: php, javascript, html

On our db, we have a fiedlname called ResultType.

There are various types of values associated with the ResultType fieldname.

Our requirement is to query our db and display values of ResultType with checkboxes so users have the option of checking one or more values.

Users can click the Check All checkbox to select all checkbox values.

Users can alternatively check the UnckAll checkboxes to unselect their selections.

A simple JS(attach) is handling this.

The problem, I am having though, is that the values of ResultType are not being displayed alongside the checkboxes.

We have file called `dbConnect.php` where connections to our sql server db, along with credentials are defined.

Something isn't right with my code below and I can't figure it out.

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function checkAll(formName, status){
       for (i = 0; i < formName.length; i++)
       formName[i].checked = status.checked? true:false
       }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Search Options</h3>

 <form name ="checkForm" method="post" action="Search.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="srcoptions"
        onClick="checkAll(this.form,this)">Check/Uncheck All
<?php

   // Connect to SQL Server database
   include("../connections/dbConnect.php");


   // Construct query
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Results";

// Execute query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Retrieve and display the results of the query
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"
       value =<font class=heading>'.$row["resultType"].'</font>><font class=heading>'.$row["resultType"].'</font><br>';
  }
  // Free statement and connection resources
  sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
  sqlsrv_close( $conn);

  ?>
  <P><input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your assistance

Comment: Err, you can't have a value of `<font class=heading>` for a checkbox (or any other element for that matter). This is invalid HTML. I would strongly encourage you to avoid coding font properties into elements - use CSS classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to produce with this line:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=<font class=heading>'.$row["resultType"].'</font>><font class=heading>'.$row["resultType"].'</font><br>';
```

but it's not going to be valid. You don't have the value quoted, and you had other HTML tags in it (which I removed but you can readd them if necessary). Try this instead:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="'.$row["resultType"].'"><font class=heading>'.$row["resultType"].'</font><br>';
```

Sidenote: You really shouldn't be using the font tag.

Comment: Tried your suggestion @David but checkboxes still don't have any values. All I see is Check/Uncheck All checkbox and the Search word.

Comment: From your text at the top, you might have a case issue. You say that the column is `ResultType`, but then you access it with `resultType`. Without seeing the database and what's coming from it, there's not much more I can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try:

```
// Retrieve and display the results of the query
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$i=0;
$i++;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[$i]"
```

Comment: working now. I screwed up by using this: `$row=mysql_fetch_array($res...` instead of this:
`$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array...` which was defined in dbConnect.php.

I apologize for wasting your time and thanks for the great suggestions by ALL.